# How do I download a file that does not have a direct link?

Tags: files, wget

For example, the file available at

`https://connect.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/marketplace/package/nuxeo-web-ui/download?version=0.8.0`

will download to a zip file in my browser, but the command

`wget https://connect.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/marketplace/package/nuxeo-web-ui/download?version=0.8.0`

will download to download?version=0.8.0 on my server. How do I correctly download files from URL's like this one?

Comment: Try `wget https://connect.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/marketplace/package/nuxeo-web-ui/download?version=0.8.0 -O foo.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` doesn't know that the file is supposed to have a particular name, so it uses the name of the web page, the last component of the URL, `download?v‌​ersion=0.8.0`.

This is your Zip file.

You could simply rename it:

```
$ mv 'download?v‌​ersion=0.8.0' file.zip
```

... or you could ask `wget` to save it with a different name from the start:

```
$ wget -O file.zip 'https://connect.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/marketplace/package/nux‌​eo-web-ui/download?v‌​ersion=0.8.0'
```

The short `-O file` option is the same as the long `--output-document=file` option. See the `wget` manual.